# Spring batch + JPA Persistance exception handling

Tags: java, jpa, exception, spring-batch

I am working in a spring batch application which writes to a database using JPA Persistence. I have a scenario, where I have to skip the exceptions during write and the job has to continue without failing.

Suppose I have 10 records to write, and record 6 will throw a SQL Exception (Table or view does not exist.) I need to skip this record and continue with the next record.

I tried implementing skippable-exception-classes but not able to skip the exception and job fails. The job throws SQL Exception **during persistence** operation(Not throwing exception in write() method).

Is 'skippable-exception-classes' really applicable to any exception occurred in JPA layer? Example if some exception happens during JPA commit, is it really possible to handle the exception using 'skippable-exception-classes' and prevent the job to rollback all the commits so far? Please help!

```
 <batch:job id="advDataExtJob" job-repository="jobRepository"
    incrementer="myIncrementerImpl" restartable="false">
    <batch:step id="myStep">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager"             
            task-executor="taskExecutor"  allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <batch:chunk reader="myReader" processor="myProcessor"
                writer="MyWriter" commit-interval="1000" skip-limit="10">

                <batch:skip-policy>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy" scope="step"/>
                </batch:skip-policy>

                <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                    <batch:include class="java.lang.Throwable"/>
                </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
            </batch:chunk>
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="StepListener"/>
                <batch:listener ref="advExtStepListener"/>
                <batch:listener ref="ItemWriteListener"/>
                <batch:listener ref="ItemSkipListener"/>
            </batch:listeners>                  
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:validator ref="dataExtJobValidator"/>
    <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="dataExtJobListener"/>
                <batch:listener ref="advExtJobListener"/>
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>
```

Skip Listener as follows

Item Skip Listener as follows

```
@Override
    public void onSkipInRead(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("skipped item: {} " + t.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInWrite(Object item, Throwable t) {
        // this.skipListener.onSkipInWrite(item, t);
        System.out.println("Here");

    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInProcess(Object item, Throwable t) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("inside skip process item " + item.toString());
        System.out.println("error is " + t.getMessage());
    }
```

Adding Console Error logs

```
  Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 1.2.0.v20091016-r5565): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01722: invalid number

Error Code: 1722
Call: INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (SESSION_ID, LAST_NM, FAP_IND, TITLE, DOB, AGE, WM_ASGN_STATUS, GENDER, MID_NM, FIRST_NM, RES_STATE_CD) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 

?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [19081, MONROE, U, MS, 1948-12-04, age-is-given-as-String-instead-of-integer, F, JANE, TEST, OR]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(org.test.batch.model.data.MyDO@5ca178da)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01722: invalid number
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    2016-08-03 18:22:51,005 ERROR [taskExecutor-1] impl.MyDomain (MyDomain.java:203) - Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 

1.2.0.v20091016-r5565): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01722: invalid number
```

Comment: According to Minella's Pro Spring Batch section on Error Handling, you need to configure two parts to skip a record. The first is choosing when a record is skipped. You have set `"java.lang.Exception"` to be included as an ignore, this will skip all exceptions, so there is no need to include the other ones.  The second configuration part is to set how many records you will allow the step to skip before letting the job fail. Try setting it to a higher number, perhaps more then 10 exceptions get thrown.

Comment: Hi Sander_M, my job has only one record to skip( and I tried giving the skip limit as 100 as well).

Comment: Allright, can you please add the (full) log of the exception to the question?

Comment: I have added the console logs in question

Comment: Thanks, but isn't this the exception you want to skip? I am more interested in seeing why your job doesn't skip the exception and was hoping to find some information on this in the log that spring batch produces...

Comment: :-) my application is built on jdbc-layer+JPA layer+Eclipse link layer. Here what I am trying is, manually produce an exception (gave age-integer column value as String) and skip this particular record-write and continue with the job. But on failed record is not skipping and job fails as such.

Comment: Can you share your full job context config file ?

Comment: Hi Sivakumar, I have added the job context file and skip listener using..

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem guys ?

Comment: @sashok_bg The problem was the method i followed to test the same scenario. Here I was testing in such a way, I process 5 records, then disconnect the network(Assuming its a possible error) and connect the network again and try to process the remaining records. Here the skip listener wont work. There is no solution to that..I found somewhere in internet, here the entire transaction has to be rolled back.

Comment: same issue facing from my side.
[how-to-handle-spring-boot-jpa-batch-execution-failed-transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58815646/how-to-handle-spring-boot-jpa-batch-execution-failed-transactions)